# Nested promise not throwing error in parent catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code :

```
return resultSet.reduce (prev,next)=> {
return function1 ({
}).then(response => {
    console.log('suscess' + someID)
    return functionA (response.someID)
}).catch (err => {
    console.log('failed' + someID)
    return functionB (response.someID)
}) 

}, promise.resolve());


function1: function (){
    return function2_Credentials().then{
        return function3_insertSqlRecord().then{
            return function4_appSearch().then (function(response){
                return function5().then (return response)
                    .catch (function (error){
                     throw Error(error);
                    });
             });
        }.catch (function(error){
                throw Error(error);
            });
    }
}.catch (function(error){
                throw Error(error);
            });
```

Inside my nested promise, if any of the inner functions failed I can get the error in catch block but it is not available function1 catch block. For example If i get function4_appSearch fails and return any error that error is accessible to the last catch block but not carried away until the function1's catch block. why am I not getting the error at  **console.log('failed' + someID)** ? and how do I get access of error from child promise untill to the parent pormise's catch block?

Comment: Only catch when you need to catch. There's no point catching just to re-throw. If you must catch/re-throw, then `throw error`.

Comment: why are you nesting promises - the whole point of Promises is to avoid the callback pyramid of doom!!!

Comment: I suggest that you read the examples of chaining here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then That's how I learned to master promises. Promise.all() is also good to read about.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code isn't valid; it has multiple syntax errors, and everything ever passed to a `.then` needs to be a Promise. Instead of

```
return function3_insertSqlRecord().then{
  return function4_appSearch().then
```

you should do something like

```
return function3_insertSqlRecord()
  .then(function4_appSearch)
  .then( // etc
```

This keeps your code flat and ensures that that the Promises each function generates are chained properly.

If you want the *caller* of `function1` to handle the error, then just let the error propagate up the Promise chain - don't `.catch` inside `function1`, because whenever you `.catch`, a *resolved Promise* results (but you want the caller to be able to see a rejected Promise). You can explicitly `throw` inside the `.catch` to make the Promise reject, but if that's all you're doing inside the `.catch`, there isn't really any point.

Try this instead:

```
function function1() {
  return function2_Credentials()
    .then(function3_insertSqlRecord)
    .then(function4_appSearch)
    .then(function5);
}
```

There also isn't any point to using `reduce` if you aren't going to use the accumulator (here, `prev`) or the item in the array you're iterating over (`next`).

Comment: how to return value from function 5 to caller of function1 ?  not able to do that with returning a new promise or just a return.

Comment: Returning the next Promise each time should work just fine. At the end, `function` will have gotten a Promise which resolves to whatever `function5` resolves to / returns.